# Generating unique ids and transformation of unique id in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, syntax, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to update a SQL table by creating two new column values : a unique Id, and then a shortened integer version *of the same* unique id just created.

Using a trick I found [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/generate-random-numbers.aspx) (see 'The NEWID() Way' towards bottom), this is what i thought would work :

```
Update Customer Set [UniqueId] = NEWID(), [UniqueIntegerId] = ABS(CAST(CAST([UniqueId] AS VARBINARY) AS INT))
```

but this generates something like

[UniqueId]   [UniqueIntegerId]

3C79...5A4DEB2    **754988032**

1FD6...828B943    **754988032**

1F48...E80F511    **754988032**  **<--- repeating! do not want!**

What syntax is correct for trying to accomplish this?

Comment: I only see repeats when I am using `NEWSEQUENTIALID` rather than `NEWID` what version of SQL Server are you on? I presume this is the constant bit for the MAC address?

Comment: Version is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1).

Comment: Although actually my test was on an `insert` not an update. Pretty sure your update will be operating on the "before" version of the `[UniqueId]` column, not the "after" version.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Indeed it will, as [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/20/sql-server-transaction-and-local-variables-swap-variables-update-all-at-once-concept/) confirms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work as expected, because `[UniqueId]` in the expression is evaluated to a value *before* the update. This is what you could try instead:

```
DECLARE @uid uniqueidentifier;
UPDATE Customer
SET
  @uid = [UniqueId] = NEWID(),
  [UniqueIntegerId] = ABS(CAST(CAST(@uid AS VARBINARY) AS INT))
```

The `@uid` variable is assigned the same value as `[UniqueId]` and is then used instead of `[UniqueId]` in the expression for the other column.

Comment: I don't think you can rely on left to right evaluation here. Seems similar to `If there are multiple assignment clauses in a single SELECT statement, SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the expressions. Note that effects are only visible if there are references among the assignments.` [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx)

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the link. I agree, it does seem similar. Yet I'm sure such things must be stated explicitly in a relevant doc article, which doesn't seem to be done with regard to updates of this kind. IMHO, this is just another dark area, similar to quirky updates (unless I'm misinterpreting the term and this UPDATE qualifies as a quirky update too). I mean, quirky updates' reliability is neither confirmed nor refuted officially. As a result, people argue endlessly pro and con on the subject, finding indirect evidence in official sources or attempting to prove their point empirically.

Comment: (By 'endlessly' I mean, people seem to stay unconvinced by other people's arguments, so the overall indefiniteness remains.)

Comment: Jeff Moden mostly! Would probably be best in this case to make `UniqueIntegerId` a computed column to avoid any doubt.

Comment: @Martin: When I first read your idea about the computed column, I thought it was nice, but that was only at first. Now, after re-reading the question, I'm more and more inclined to agree with you that it's probably the best solution, so, um... mm? (That is, ‘how about posting it as an answer’?)